# Creating an installer for multiple applications

Tags: c#, installation

Hey, I'm trying to create an installer for multiple games, from one server computer which individual computers then execute.
E.g. BF 1942, WC3, BF2, DOW. However i need to be able to select which applications to Install, which is a simple check box.
I only have a limited knowledge of c#. What is the best way of going about this?
I have looked at NSIS though i don't like the scripting that they use.
I only have C# express.

Comment: If your programming knowledge is limited, and at the same time you're not prepared to learn a simple language like the one that NSIS uses, you're probably in the wrong place here. You'll have a much better chance of getting a useful answer on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

NSIS. http://nsis.sourceforge.net One section per application, install with ExecWait operation.

```
Section "BF 1942"
    ExecWait '"$EXEDIR\1942\setup.exe"'
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing that I can think of would probably have to be `iexpress.exe`

It comes standard with 99% of all windows, just do CTRL+R and type in `iexpress.exe`.

It's a wizard, so it shouldn't be that hard to generate your own file.

I don't know if it would work for what you're wanting to do, but I'd consider it to be worth trying, saving yourself some time.